# Assign file names to a variable in shell

Tags: bash, shell, variables, for-loop, ls

I'm trying to write a script that does something a bit more sophisticated than what I'm going to show you, but I know that the problem is in this part.

I want each name of a list of files in a directory to be assigned to a variable (the same variable, one at a time) through a `for` loop, then do something inside of the loop with this, see what mean:

```
for thing in $(ls $1);
do
    file $thing;
done
```

Edit: let's say this scrypt is called Scrypt and I have a folder named Folder, and it has 3 files inside named A,B,C. I want it to show me on the terminal when I write this:

```
./scrypt Folder
```

the following:

```
A: file
B: file
C: file
```

With the code I've shown above, I get this:

```
A: ERROR: cannot open `A' (No such file or directory)
B: ERROR: cannot open `B' (No such file or directory)
C: ERROR: cannot open `C' (No such file or directory)
```

that is the problem

Comment: What's wrong? What you have should work just fine exactly as it is.

Comment: Yes, the only thing wrong here is breaking on whitespace.

Comment: well it says doing this for each file: ERROR: cannot open `file'(no such file or directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use wildcard expansion instead of `ls`, e.g.,

```
for filename in "$1"/*; do
    command "$filename"
done
```

This assumes that `$1` is the path to a directory with files in it.

If you want to only operate on plain files, add a check right after `do` along the lines of:

```
[ ! -f "$filename" ] && continue
```

Comment: The best way, assuming each `$1` is a folder.

Comment: that would assing the directory name to filename, I need to give the name of the files inside the directory to filename.

Comment: @Zasito: No, this would assign in turn the entire path to the files in that directory. If you need only the filename, you can use `basename "$filename"` to extract just the filename without the path.

Comment: @Arkku: If i replace this on the thing I wrote on the question it will show me on the terminal this: $1: directory. Let's say that we put folder as the Argument, and it has inside 3 files A, B, C. When i write ./scrypt folder I want it to show A:file B:file C:file, if i put this, it will show only folder: directory.

Comment: @Zasito: Did you copypaste the code exactly as shown, including quotes and the `/*` directly attached to the quote after `$1`? Also, do you have some other code in the script first, or did you test it with nothing but the code shown in my answer (with `command` replaced by `echo` or `file`)?

Comment: waw! I assumed the /* was something else (starting in shell, I only know c++), so omitted it! Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Use globbing instead:

```
for filename in "$1"/* ; do
    <cmd> "$filename"
done
```

Note the quotes around $filename

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you are trying to accomplish, but you can essentially do the same thing with functionality that already exists with `find`. For example, the following prints the contents of each file found in a folder:

```
find FolderName -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec cat {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

well,
i think that what you meant is that the loop will show the filenames in the desired dir.
so, i would do it like that:

```
for filename in "$1"/*; do
echo "file: $filename"
done
```

that way the result should be (in case in the dir are 3 files and the names are A B C:

```
`file: A
`file: B
`file: C
```