# How to print out a file name to set to variable with bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to set the name of a file to a variable with a shell script. I've searched online and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519442/assign-file-names-to-a-variable-in-shell), but it is not helping me achieve what I'd like to do which is the following:

```
JSFILE=ls build/static/js/ | head -1
CSSFILE=ls build/static/css/ | head -1
```

With, `ls ${path} | head -1` I am able to print out the file I want to set a variable to but I keep seeing the following error/output when I try to set the name of the file I want to a variable:

`deploy.sh: line 1: build/static/js/: is a directory`

Does anyone know how to print out the name of a file to set it to variable in bash?

Comment: Tip: If you run [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/)  on your script, it will suggest "[SC2209](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2209): Use var=$(command) to assign output (or quote to assign string)."

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the name of the script which executes your commands?
use **$0**. i.e.

```
MYVAR=$0
```