# Processing list of files variable in bash

Tags: bash

Using `myscript mydir/*` I don't understand why bash is processing only the first element with the code below.

```
#!/bin/bash

files="$1"

for f in "$files"; do
  echo "Processing $f"
done
```

What do I miss so that I can process a list of files given as an argument to the script?

Comment: I don't think that question answer's Marc's question but I think this one does: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13519442/14079207

Comment: @Marc: `files` contains a single string (the first argument to your program), and the argument list of your `for ... in` also contains only a single string (the content of `files`). Hence the loop will be executed exactly once. If you want to iterate over all the arguments passed to your program, you have to use the special expression `"$@"`: `for f in "$@"`.